# How to make flutter ask user for adding huawei protected app once app opend

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I've created a Flutter app for both  android and ios
I'm using:

1. Flutter 1.17
2. One-Signal for push notifications 2.5 for Flutter

The problem is in some devices the notifications not showing due to the Huawei protected app's permission. I tried to find and way to ask users for adding the app to the Huawei protected app once they open the app, but can't find any resource for that

please  solution in flutter

Comment: no  , iam using flutter  and the awnser you reefer for is based on deffrent framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After work around these
the best solution was to publish the app through Hawaii app gallery , and using HMS

also you can access  app settings and let user  whitelist the app
using this  https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings